# Replacing a line in a file with Python doesn't work like it's supposed to

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot and tryying to save stats about every user and their messages sent but it's not working. This is what I have:

```
async def update_stats():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    global messages, author
    data = []
    if author != 0:
        try:
            with open("stats.txt", "r") as f:
                data = f.readlines()
                for item in data:
                    author2, messages2 = item.split(":")
                    print(author2, messages2)
                    index = data.index(item)

                if author == author2:

                    with open("stats.txt", "w") as f1:
                        data.pop(index)
                        novi_stat = f"""{author}:{int(messages) + int(messages2)}\n"""
                        data.insert(index, novi_stat)
                        str = ''.join(data)
                        f1.write(str)
                else:
                    with open("stats.txt", "w") as f2:
                        data.append(f"""{author}:{messages}\n""")
                        str = ''.join(data)
                        f2.write(str)

            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

And this is the content of the text file it loads and is supposed to change when number of messages changes:

```
DrDEagle#4984:100
kreten:123
```

This is what I get when running the code:

```
DrDEagle#4984:100
kreten:123
:0
```

It is supposed to change the number from 100 to 101 if I send one message, but instead it writes a new line which doesn't even contain the right data, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: After an hour of editing and rewriting the code, I did this and it works.

```
import discord
import random
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import json
import datetime


client = discord.Client()
sentdex_guild = client.get_guild(No, No!) # I didn't post the code...

author = ''
messages = 0
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global author, messages
    author = message.author.name
    messages += 1
    authorsInFile = []

    f = open("stats.txt", 'r')
    data = f.readlines()
    for item in data:
        author2, messages2 = item.split(":")
        authorsInFile.append(author2)
        print(author2, messages2)
        if author in authorsInFile:
            index = authorsInFile.index(author)
        else:
            pass

    if author2 == author:

        f1 = open("stats.txt", "w")
        print(author)
        data.pop(index)
        novi_stat = f"""{author}:{int(messages2) + 1}\n"""
        data.insert(index, novi_stat)
        str = ''.join(data)
        f1.write(str)
        f1.close()
        f.close()

    else:
        f2 = open("stats.txt", "w")
        data.append(f"""{author}:{messages}\n""")
        str = ''.join(data)
        f2.write(str)
        f2.close()
        f.close()

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f"""{datetime.datetime.now()} | {message.author} je rekao: {message.content}\n""")

    if message.content == "!bok":
        await message.channel.send("Pozdrav!")

    elif message.content == "!korisnici":
        online = 0
        idle = 0
        offline = 0

        for m in sentdex_guild.members:
            if str(m.status) == "online":
                online += 1
            if str(m.status) == "offline":
                offline += 1
            else:
                idle += 1
        await message.channel.send(f"""Broj korisnika: {online+offline - 1}\nˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ\nOnline korisnika: {online - 1}\nOffline korisnika: {offline}\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^""") # printa broj korisnika, ali ne broji sebe

    elif message.content == "!ping":
        latency = client.latency
        await message.channel.send(f"""Moj ping iznosi {round(latency, 6)}ms""")

    elif message.content == "!yacketty":
        await message.channel.send("Dostupne komande su: !ping, !bok, !korisnici, !bitcoin...")

    elif message.content == "!bitcoin":
        url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json'
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:  # Async HTTP request
            raw_response = await session.get(url)
            response = await raw_response.text()
            response = json.loads(response)
            await message.channel.send("Cijena bitcoina: $" + response['bpi']['USD']['rate'])

    elif "!8ball" in message.content:
        moguci_odgovori = [
            'Nema jebene šanse',
            'Možda, ali samo možda',
            'Ahhh, 50-50',
            'Vrlo moguće',
            'Apsolutno da'
        ]
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(moguci_odgovori) + ", " + message.author.mention)

@client.event
async def welcome(member):
    for channel in member.server.channels:
        if str(channel) == "general":
            await client.send_message(f"""{member.mention}, dobrodošao na server!""")

client.run("I'm not showing you this hehe")
```

Comment: Rather than saving that data in a text file, you should use a database, like `sqlite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that you set either `author` or `messages`.  You have them set as globals, so I assume you're setting them before calling this function. If `author` is an empty string, and `messages` is 0, then the output you are getting is just what I would expect from your code.

Since there is not yet an author named "", it appends an entry for that author to the file that is the empty author name, a colon, and the 0 that is the value of `message`.

Note that your first `if` test would succeed and the `if` block entered in this proposed case, as `"" != 0` is `True`.

Another observation...you're reading in multiple existing authors, but you seem to be only comparing the passed in author against the last author read in from the file.  I'm assuming that's not what you want...you probably want to be comparing each author you read in against the passed in author in the loop that is processing each line of the file.

Comment: You are right, I set them before calling this function: `author = ""
messages = 0
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global messages, author
    author = message.author
    messages += 1
    print(author)` is the fact that I'm setting `author = ""` before making it global the source of my problem?

Comment: You can add new code to your question.  Often, people do this and mark it clearly as an "UPDATE:".  This would let you show your code in a formatted way instead of how you have to do it in comments where its really hard to read.  It's more appropriate anyway, as it's really a part of your question.  I don't exactly follow the order of all you're talking about, but it could definitely be the case that putting a "global author" in the wrong place could mess up your logic.

Comment: If you can stop in a debugger and watch your code run, that's the best way to debug stuff like this.  If not, then just put in lots of log/print statements to find out for sure just what the values of your important variables are at various stages of your execution.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up deleting the whole function and executing the code every time someone sends a message. Now it works flawlessly.